# How to select values in a dataframe using pyspark?

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I am trying to select values from a column in a dataframe based upon a string, like UNKNOWN.

```
newDF = experimentsDF.select(experimentsDF.labs_col WHEN (experimentsDF.expirenement_desc == 'UNKNOWN'))
```

I am using pyspark and I don't have the syntax correct.

Can you help me select the values in the labs_col?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pyspark has the filter function to perform this:

```
experimentsDF.filter(experimentsDF.expirenement_desc == 'UNKNOWN').select('labs_col')
```

You can also use the Where function:

```
experimentsDF.where(col('expirenement_desc ')=='UNKOWN').select('labs_col')
```

Comment: Thanks, for the help.  This is what I need.